# Need help using C# FindControl

Tags: c#, .net, repeater, findcontrol

I have a repeater inside a panel.
Inside this repeater I have another panel.Upon certain conditions, I want to set this `panel.visibility = false`.

In the code behind, I try locating the panels on `OnItemDataBound` and set visible=false.  But it only returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. I guesing it's because it can't locate the panel.

Here is my code:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repComments_OnDataBound">    
             <ItemTemplate>                         
                <div>
                   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="commentAdminPanel" CssClass="floatRight" >
                     <img id='deleteComment' class='deleteComment' src='/img/delete1.jpg' />  
                   </asp:Panel>                     
                </div>
              </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
     </asp:Panel>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
    protected void repComments_OnDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)Repeater1.FindControl("commentAdminPanel");
        panel.Visible = false;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that you are calling the repeater directly, instead of the bound item template - `e.Item.FindControl` instead of `Repeater1.FindControl`.

The other issue is that the `ItemDataBound` event will also fire for header and footer, and you are not checking the type of list item ([ListItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemtype.aspx) enum) you are on in the repeater.

Since you don't have a header item (which would be the first item to call the handler), there is no panel control and the cast fails.

You only need the `Item` and `AlternatingItem` item types:

```
protected void repComments_OnDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem )
    {
        Panel panel = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("commentAdminPanel");
        panel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be e.Item.FindControl instead of Repeater1.FindControl